# All primitives continuous function

Tags: integration

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b],$ for each $c\in[a,b],$ the integral of $f$ from $c$ to $x$ is a primitive of $f$ in $[a,b].$ Is the set of integrals of that kind the set of all primitives of $f$ in $[a,b]?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $f:(0, 2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = \cos x$. The set of primitives are functions of the form $F(x) = \sin x + C$ where $C$ is an arbitrary real number.

However, $F(x)$ can be expressed as $\int_c^x \cos t  \ dt= \sin x - \sin c $ where $c \in (0, 2\pi)$ only when the constant $C$ is within the interval $[-1, 1]$.

In general, if $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, the biconditional $$F \ \text{is a primitive of f} \Longleftrightarrow \text{There is a} \  c \in (a,b) \ \text{such that} \ F\  \text{can be expressed as} \int_c^x f(t) \ dt$$

holds if and only if $F$ is surjective onto $\mathbb{R}$ (the domain of $F$ is $(a,b)$).

Of course, you can replace $(a,b)$ with any open, connected $I \subset \mathbb{R}$. Or closed intervals, but then we have to work with right- and left- derivatives, which is a bit ugly to me.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion is clear. However, any function of this form $\int_c^xf(x)dx+k$ is a primitive, and $k$ is arbitrary, so the set $\{\int_c^xf(x)dx|c\in[a,b]\} $ may not be the all primitive functions.